# LibGDX: FileHandle in html

Tags: libgdx

```
    FileHandle dirHandle = Gdx.files.internal("audio/");
    int size = dirHandle.list().length;
```

There is 10 files in `audio` folder.
The above code works properly in Android and Desktop but in Html, `size` is zero.

Comment: On which version are you? Prior 1.9.12 the functionality was not working on HTML

Comment: My gdx version was 1.9.10 The problem was solved after the update. Thankful 
 @MrStahlfelge